# Xpath - find nodes that start with the same name -- via wildcards or boolean ops?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

How can I find the Xpath Nodes that start with the same name?

For example, to find all nodes starting with '**rol**' :: <**rol1**>, <**rol2**> and <**rol3**> etc?

Suppose I have the following XML file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <name>Name 2</name>
        <rol1>Role 1</rol1>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <name>Name 1</name>
        <rol2>Role 2</rol2>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I would like to find the nodes "rol1" and "rol2". In reality, there could be like 6 roles in the XML file.

Q1: How can I do that with an XPath search with wildcards like 'role*'?
Q2: And with boolean operators matching "role1" and "role2"? 
Q3: When I query a single result using XPath regex and there is no role*, than nothing or null should be found.

In the examples I found, only regex's are used for searching using attributes.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q1: How can I do that with an XPath search with wildcards like 'role*'?

To find all elements which name without namespace-prefix does start with 'role' use this expression:

```
//*[starts-with(local-name(),'role')]
```

> Q2: And with boolean operators matching "role1" and "role2"?

You can do this by using the boolean operators in the *predicate* of the XPath expression.
(the following example does not return a useful result and is only here for illustrative purpose)

```
//*[starts-with(local-name(),'role1') and starts-with(local-name(),'role2')]
```

> Q3: When I query a single result using XPath regex and there is no role*, than nothing or null should be found.

An empty nodeset is always returned when there are no matches.